# ASP.Net MVC:How to inject Bootstrap js validation code in page based on built-in data annotation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, validation

We know that for client side validation logic related js code is automatically injected into page but that js code is related to unobtrusive library.

Now I am thinking that I will not use unobtrusive library at client side side validation rather I will use bootstrap js validation, but I do not want to manually write code for client side validation using bootstrap client side api.

See few url where bootstrap client side js api has been used to validate form

http://www.devcurry.com/2014/08/validate-form-using-jquery-and_5.html
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/powerful-form-field-validator-for-jquery-and-bootstrap-using/

So when anyone check my above link then must see that author wrote bootstrap js related code for client side validation, but I want to inject bootstrap js related code for client side validation automatically in the page just like unobtrusive library.

As we know unobtrusive library related js code is injected into page based on built-in data annotation and the same way I want to inject Bootstrap js validation code in page based on built-in data annotation.

I got this link after search http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/12/17/Implementing-validation-callout-in-Aspnet-MVC-(with-data-annotations).aspx

Which gave some clue but still I am not close to my goal.

Please tell me how it will be possible ?

Or redirect me to relevant article which help me to do it.